# Why are images sized differently on Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I've been working on my [personal portfolio](https://mirceacasapu.com) and i was developing on Firefox. There is a skills section that was styled using flexbox, that contains a logo and its name

```css
.abilities-flex-container{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.abilities-flex-paragraph{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 7rem;
  max-height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="abilities-flex-container">
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/480px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="HTML5" class="img-fluid">HTML5
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/340px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="CSS3" class="img-fluid">CSS
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/128px-Unofficial_JavaScript_logo_2.svg.png" alt="Javascript" class="img-fluid">JavaScript
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/128px-Octicons-database.svg.png" alt="SQL" class="img-fluid">SQL
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/getbootstrap-icon.svg" alt="Bootstrap" class="img-fluid">Bootstrap
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/jquery-icon.svg" alt="jQuery" class="img-fluid">jQuery
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/dotnet-icon.svg" alt="ASP.NET" class="img-fluid">ASP.NET
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/java-icon.svg" alt="Java" class="img-fluid">Java
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/200px-C_Sharp_logo.svg.png" alt="C#" class="img-fluid">C#
    </p>
    <p class="abilities-flex-paragraph">
        <img src="Images/Icons/128px-ISO_C++_Logo.svg.png" alt="C/C++" class="img-fluid">C/C++
    </p>
</div>
```

My problem is that on Firefox, the images don't go over their max-height of 5rem, but on chrome they do. Haven't tested it on other browsers, and I'm stumped. You can see it on my portfolio if you check it

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying styles directly to the image tag

```
abilities-flex-paragraph > img {
    max-width: 5rem;
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it

```
.abilities-flex-paragraph > img {
max-width: 5rem;
```

}

did the trick